# How to obtain the high accuracy of value in iOS

Tags: ios, json, numbers

The Server response a 'json object' to me :

```
the json:
{ wareAmount:"13.40" } ;
```

My iOS code is to get this json value and push in a block :

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self ;
[taskAction invoke:(NSDictionary *result){
    weakSelf.wareAmount = [[result objectForKey:@"wareAmount"] doubleValue];
    // the weakSelf.wareAmount's value is 13.399936 ...
}] ;
```

why wareAmount's (wareAmount is the self's property object) value is 13.39, not 13.40 ?

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON to the Dictionary? Are you using a library or apple internal methods?

Comment: 1、My project have a function that parsing all JSON to a Dictionary Object and push in callback block  ; 2、It's not apple's internal methods ; 3、In breakpoint , I can see the result's value is 13.40 in block , but  weakSelf.wareAmount's value is 13.399 , I don't know the reason ;

Comment: 4、Could you tell me why the reason  ;

Comment: 5、I  need to get 13.40 rather than 13.399 ， Could you help me ?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to create the dictionary?

Comment: Also the JSON seems a little weird. It should be something like:
`{ "wareAmount" : 13.40 } ` (note the quotation marks)

Comment: OK， but {  wareAmount:"13.40"  } is Server's reponse ， it's not be created on the iphone device

Comment: Ok, then your JSON parsing is broken. Just debug into the block and then inspect your `result` dictionary. Is it wrong there already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of how computers store floating point values. This is a huge topic on which I'd suggest you read some more (starting maybe [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)). The bottom line is that there is no way to precisely express decimal numbers in computers.

To somehow mitigate your problem, I'd suggest storing your numbers as `NSNumber` or even `NSDecimalNumber` (this is even suggested for storing values representing amounts of money).

Comment: I don't know what precision you would have to have, to not be able to accurately represent 13.4. Float8 maybe? :) 
I think in this specific case the parsing (which we don't know how it's done) is messed up